# Angular mattooltip with if condition and i18n translation

Tags: angular, internationalization

I try to combine the mattooltip with translation.
This works:

`[matTooltip]="getValue() == 0 ? 'foo' : 'bar'"`

This does not

`[matTooltip]="getValue() == 0 ? {{ I18N:foo.bar}} : 'bar'"`

How do I get the translation built in at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a pipe

[Mattooltip]="getValue() | pipename | translate"

Answer (score 0):

if you are already between the " " you don't need the {{ }}, try :

[matTooltip]="getValue() == 0 ? I18N:foo.bar : 'bar'"

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. It really shows me I18N:foo.bar as tooltip and not the needed translation